# Testing AsyncValidators in Angular - tests pass but not sure the expect statements are being run/executed

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

i am currently writing an AsyncValidator for my form that checks a value submitted has a value, then checks it against a string array contained in the Component where it is used and if all is good it calls an api...this is what it looks like...

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DomainUniqueValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  validate(
    input: FormControl
  ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return timer(500)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          if (!input.value) {
            return of(null);
          }

          // check that the domain isn't already in the domains array
          // @ts-ignore - Property domains does not exist in DomainUniqueValidator. this is addEditDomainComponent
          if (this.domains.indexOf(input.value) > -1) { // this.domains is a string[]
            return of({ domainTakenInList: true });
          }
          // @ts-ignore - 
          return this.api.isDomainUnique(input.value, this.domainToEdit?.id).pipe(
            map((res: any) => ({ domainTaken: true })),
            catchError(() => null)
          );
        })
      );
  }
}
```

All works well but it is time for me to write my unit tests. I started writing a test to check that he input.value exists and the code that checks for existence in the this.domains string array. My first test seems to work, but my second doesn't. Here's my code.

```
describe('DomainUniqueValidator', () => {
    let validator;
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      validator = new DomainUniqueValidator();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      getTestBed().resetTestingModule();
    });

    it('should return null', () => {
      const control = { value: null };
      const result = validator.validate(control as any);
      result.subscribe({
        next(res): void {
          expect(res).toEqual(null); // this seems to work
        }
      });
    });

    it('should return a domainTakenInList error', () => {
      const control = { value: 'google.com', domains: ['mozilla.com', 'google.com'] };
      // @ts-ignore
      const result = validator.validate(control as FormControl);
      result.subscribe({
        next(res): void {
          console.log('hello'); // not ran?
          expect(res).toEqual({ domainTakenInList: true }); 
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Although the second test passes I think something is wrong, I don't think the code inside the second test's result.subscribe is executed. I don' think the `expect` statements are being executed. I am thinking that maybe the way I have set up my tests may be incorrect as I tried writing to the console inside the next of the second test's subscribe property but this isn't executed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

async values can indeed be skipped by jasmine tests. to handle it correctly there is a possibility to pass `done` callback to tests. if you accept this param jasmine will consider your test async and will w8 untill you call the done callback

```
it('test' (done) => {
   asyncSomething(params, result => {
      expect(...)...
      done();
   })
});
```

Comment: why? put done as a param and call it after your expect. that will make sure that expect will be called before the test completes